# Cannot pass callback lambdas into .toReactivePublisher().subscribe() in Spring Integration with Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

I'm getting an error of `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No subscriptions have been created` when I use Spring Integration with Project Reactor and I try to figure out how can I subscribe. My original code was:

```java
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow writeToKafka() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.receiveAutoAck()
                .map(payload -> {
                    return new GenericMessage<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>(payload);
                }))
            .<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>transform(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .channel(c -> c.queue("resultChannel"))
            .get();
    }
```

After it threw the error I've tried to subscribe but I've couldn't understand what should I pass to the subscribe method, that seems to act differently than the regular reactive `.subscribe()`.

```java
    @Bean
    public void writeToKafka() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.receiveAutoAck()
                .map(payload -> {
                    return new GenericMessage<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>(payload);
                }))
            .<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>transform(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .channel(c -> c.queue("resultChannel"))
            .toReactivePublisher().subscribe(value -> {
                log.info("Wrote: " + value);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that `.toReactivePublisher().subscribe()` combination is not correct. The `IntegrationFlow` must be first exposed and configured as a bean. And only then, after injecting this bean somewhere in your service you can `subscribe()` to that `Publisher` bean.

You are missing the fact that inversion of control has to be initialized first in its dependency injection container and only after that we can do some real work (subscribe) with those beans.

**EDIT**

For example my test-case:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@DirtiesContext
public class ReactiveStreamsTests {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pollableReactiveFlow")
    private Publisher<Message<Integer>> pollablePublisher;

    @Autowired
    private AbstractEndpoint reactiveTransformer;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("inputChannel")
    private MessageChannel inputChannel;

    @Test
    void testPollableReactiveFlow() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.reactiveTransformer).isInstanceOf(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.class);
        this.inputChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("1,2,3,4,5"));

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(6);

        Flux.from(this.pollablePublisher)
                .take(6)
                .filter(m -> m.getHeaders().containsKey(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER))
                .doOnNext(p -> latch.countDown())
                .subscribe();

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<List<Integer>> future =
                exec.submit(() ->
                        Flux.just("11,12,13")
                                .map(v -> v.split(","))
                                .flatMapIterable(Arrays::asList)
                                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                                .<Message<Integer>>map(GenericMessage::new)
                                .concatWith(this.pollablePublisher)
                                .take(7)
                                .map(Message::getPayload)
                                .collectList()
                                .block(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                );

        this.inputChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("6,7,8,9,10"));

        assertThat(latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        List<Integer> integers = future.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        assertThat(integers).isNotNull();
        assertThat(integers.size()).isEqualTo(7);
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Publisher<Message<Integer>> pollableReactiveFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows
                    .from("inputChannel")
                    .split(s -> s.delimiters(","))
                    .<String, Integer>transform(Integer::parseInt,
                            e -> e.reactive(flux -> flux.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())).id("reactiveTransformer"))
                    .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                    .log()
                    .toReactivePublisher();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example?

Comment: See an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a lot, but my need is pretty different since I do try to use `IntegrationFlow`. I've asked a new question with more accurate examples for my need.